# How to count nodes and get attribute value without using xpath

Tags: shell-script, xml, xmllint

Currently I have a shell script like this:

```
LOGIN=`curl 'https://www.ponta.jp/u/LWAS900/SLWAS900010.htm' -sS | grep '<input type="hidden" name\|<form\|</form'`

for i in $(seq $(printf "$LOGIN" | xmllint --xpath "count(/form/input)" -))
do
    printf " -d "
    printf "$LOGIN" | xmllint --xpath "string(/form/input[$i]/@name)" -
    printf "="
    printf "$LOGIN" | xmllint --xpath "string(/form/input[$i]/@value)" -
done
```

I want to do the same thing on a unix environment which doesn't have xpath. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Surely not with [regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Comment: is installing a library an option? I would be suggesting `perl` and `XML::Twig` as a starting point, because that ... is another way of doing xpath style searches on your input.

Answer (score 0):

A XML parser based solution is the way to go. 
Nevertheless here goes a quick regular expression hack:

```
LOGIN=...
printf "$LOGIN" | 
    perl -nE 'say "-d $1=$2" if /name="(.*?)".*?value="(.*)"/'
```